# Visual Composer image carousel doesn't loop properly

Tags: jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, visual-composer

It's my first post, so please be forgiving for my english.

I have an issue with Image Carousel VC component. I need to set up something like logotypes slider (5 logos in a row) and when i set it up to display 5 from 6 images there is a gap on the end (like 4 empty spaces).

My seting:

6 images added,
Slides per view: 5,
Slider loop: yes

Goal is to set up carouse to be looped, without any empty spaces between images.

There is also a responsive issue. When i resize browser window images losing their ratio (width is scaling percentage and height is fixed).

Can anyone help me deal with that?

Comment: Responsive issue: width is %, height is fixed? That should distort the images. Width % and height: auto styles you the image so it is responsive to width changes, without aspect ratio changes.

Comment: This should fix your issue. Make sure to add vc_custominfiniteloop as the extra class name https://humbertosilva.com/visual-composer-infinite-image-carousel/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Porting Humberto Silva's [post](https://humbertosilva.com/visual-composer-infinite-image-carousel/) into a Stack Overflow answer, it seems there's no built-in way to do this, but there's a workaround in JavaScript.

First, add an extra class `vc_custominfiniteloop` to the carousel element.

[image: visual composer carousel infinite loop]

Then, add this JavaScript code after jQuery and Visual Composer javascript has been loaded:

```
/*
Turn Visual Composer Image Carousel into Visual Composer Infinite Image Carousel
Include before the </head> tag on yout theme's header.php 
Read the detailed step-by-step at https://humbertosilva.com/visual-composer-infinite-image-carousel/
*/

// auxiliary code to create triggers for the add and remove class for later use
(function($){
$.each(["addClass","removeClass"],function(i,methodname){
    var oldmethod = $.fn[methodname];
    $.fn[methodname] = function(){
          oldmethod.apply( this, arguments );
          this.trigger(methodname+"change");
          return this;
    }
});
})(jQuery);

// main function for the infinite loop
function vc_custominfiniteloop_init(vc_cil_element_id){

  var vc_element = '#' + vc_cil_element_id; // because we're using this more than once let's create a variable for it
  window.maxItens = jQuery(vc_element).data('per-view'); // max visible items defined
  window.addedItens = 0; // auxiliary counter for added itens to the end 

  // go to slides and duplicate them to the end to fill space
  jQuery(vc_element).find('.vc_carousel-slideline-inner').find('.vc_item').each(function(){
    // we only need to duplicate the first visible images
    if (window.addedItens < window.maxItens) {
      if (window.addedItens == 0 ) {
        // the fisrt added slide will need a trigger so we know it ended and make it "restart" without animation
        jQuery(this).clone().addClass('vc_custominfiniteloop_restart').removeClass('vc_active').appendTo(jQuery(this).parent());            
      } else {
        jQuery(this).clone().removeClass('vc_active').appendTo(jQuery(this).parent());         
      }
      window.addedItens++;
    }
  });

  // add the trigger so we know when to "restart" the animation without the user knowing about it
  jQuery('.vc_custominfiniteloop_restart').bind('addClasschange', null, function(){

    // navigate to the carousel element , I know, its ugly ...
    var vc_carousel = jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();

    // first we temporarily change the animation speed to zero
    jQuery(vc_carousel).data('vc.carousel').transition_speed = 0;

    // make the slider go to the first slide without animation and because the fist set of images shown
    // are the same that are being shown now the slider is now "restarted" without that being visible 
    jQuery(vc_carousel).data('vc.carousel').to(0);

    // allow the carousel to go to the first image and restore the original speed 
    setTimeout("vc_cil_restore_transition_speed('"+jQuery(vc_carousel).prop('id')+"')",100);
  });

}

// restore original speed setting of vc_carousel
function vc_cil_restore_transition_speed(element_id){
// after inspecting the original source code the value of 600 is defined there so we put back the original here
jQuery('#' + element_id).data('vc.carousel').transition_speed = 600; 
}

// init     
jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
  // find all vc_carousel with the defined class and turn them into infine loop
  jQuery('.vc_custominfiniteloop').find('div[data-ride="vc_carousel"]').each(function(){
    // allow time for the slider to be built on the page
    // because the slider is "long" we can wait a bit before adding images and events needed  
    var vc_cil_element = jQuery(this).prop("id");
    setTimeout("vc_custominfiniteloop_init('"+vc_cil_element+"')",2000);      
  });    
});
```

If you're having trouble, try enqueuing it with PHP_INT_MAX and depending on jQuery, example:

```
function enqueue_my_scripts()
{
    // This example expects you to create a file with the JavaScript above in wp-content/themes/yourtheme/assets/js/infinite_visualcomposer_carousel.js
    wp_enqueue_script('infinite-vs-carousel',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/infinite_visualcomposer_carousel.js', array('jquery'), filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/assets/js/infinite_visualcomposer_carousel.js'), true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts', PHP_INT_MAX);
```

All credits to Humberto Silva, I'm just porting this answer here to save the solution in case the blog goes offline.

Comment: Found this very useful. However, in the enqueue scripts function, the first reference to your assets/js/infinite_visualcomposer_carousel.js file is missing a forward slash

Answer (score 1):

/*
Turn Visual Composer Image Carousel into Visual Composer Infinite Image Carousel
Include before the  tag on yout theme's header.php
Read the detailed step-by-step at https://humbertosilva.com/visual-composer-infinite-image-carousel/
*/

```
    // auxiliary code to create triggers for the add and remove class for later use
    (function($){
    $.each(["addClass","removeClass"],function(i,methodname){
        var oldmethod = $.fn[methodname];
        $.fn[methodname] = function(){
              oldmethod.apply( this, arguments );
              this.trigger(methodname+"change");
              return this;
        }
    });
    })(jQuery);

    // init     
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){    
      // find all vc_carousel with the defined class and turn them into infine loop
      jQuery('.vc_custominfiniteloop').find('div[data-ride="vc_carousel"]').each(function(){
        // allow time for the slider to be built on the page
        // because the slider is "long" we can wait a bit before adding images and events needed  
        var vc_cil_element = jQuery(this).prop("id");
        
        setTimeout(vc_custominfiniteloop_init(vc_cil_element),3000);      
      });    
    });

    // main function for the infinite loop
    function vc_custominfiniteloop_init(vc_cil_element_id){

      var vc_element = '#' + vc_cil_element_id; // because we're using this more than once let's create a variable for it
     
      window.maxItens = jQuery(vc_element).data('per-view'); // max visible items defined
      window.addedItens = 0; // auxiliary counter for added itens to the end 

      // go to slides and duplicate them to the end to fill space
      jQuery(vc_element).find('.vc_carousel-slideline-inner').find('.vc_item').each(function(){
        // we only need to duplicate the first visible images
        if (window.addedItens < window.maxItens) {
          if (window.addedItens == 0 ) {
            // the fisrt added slide will need a trigger so we know it ended and make it "restart" without animation
            jQuery(this).clone().addClass('vc_custominfiniteloop_restart').removeClass('vc_active').appendTo(jQuery(this).parent());            
          } else {
            jQuery(this).clone().removeClass('vc_active').appendTo(jQuery(this).parent());         
          }
          window.addedItens++;
        }
      });

      // add the trigger so we know when to "restart" the animation without the user knowing about it
      jQuery('.vc_custominfiniteloop_restart').bind('addClasschange', null, function(){

        // navigate to the carousel element , I know, its ugly ...
        var vc_carousel = jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();

        // first we temporarily change the animation speed to zero
        jQuery(vc_carousel).data('vc.carousel').transition_speed = 0;

        // make the slider go to the first slide without animation and because the fist set of images shown
        // are the same that are being shown now the slider is now "restarted" without that being visible 
        jQuery(vc_carousel).data('vc.carousel').to(0);

        // allow the carousel to go to the first image and restore the original speed 
        setTimeout(vc_cil_restore_transition_speed(jQuery(vc_carousel).prop('id')),5000);
      });

      // // restore original speed setting of vc_carousel
    function vc_cil_restore_transition_speed(element_id){
    // after inspecting the original source code the value of 600 is defined there so we put back the original here
    jQuery('#' + element_id).data('vc.carousel').transition_speed = 5000; 
    }

    }
```

All credits to Humberto Silva, I'm just porting this answer here to save the solution in case the blog goes offline.

Just Has Done some Fixes on this code according to my need. So Don't bother to Ask why i paste the same code....